# Remove a array from PHP file

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to remove some strings pointing to CSS files inside a PHP file. While I've mostly achieved this with PHP unlink() , the codes appear in the page source and I want to prevent this.

How can I remove some of them as in the example below?

**Php File Name**: css-files.php

```
<?php

return array(
    // Single product.
    'woo-single-prod-opt-review-images'                         => array(
        array(
            'title' => esc_html__( 'Single product review images', 'woodmart' ),
            'name'  => 'woo-single-prod-opt-review-images',
            'file'  => '/css/parts/woo-single-prod-opt-review-images',
        ),
    ),
    'woo-single-prod-el-reviews'                                => array(
        array(
            'title' => esc_html__( 'Single product reviews', 'woodmart' ),
            'name'  => 'woo-single-prod-el-reviews',
            'file'  => '/css/parts/woo-single-prod-el-reviews',
        ),
    ),
    'woo-single-prod-el-base'                                   => array(
        array(
            'title' => esc_html__( 'Single product elements base', 'woodmart' ),
            'name'  => 'woo-single-prod-el-base',
            'file'  => '/css/parts/woo-single-prod-el-base',
        ),
    ),
    'woo-single-prod-el-gallery'                                => array(
        array(
            'title' => esc_html__( 'Single product gallery', 'woodmart' ),
            'name'  => 'woo-single-prod-el-gallery',
            'file'  => '/css/parts/woo-single-prod-el-gallery',
            'rtl'   => true,
        ),
    ),
    'woo-single-prod-el-gallery-opt-thumb-left'                 => array(
        array(
            'title' => esc_html__( 'Single product gallery left', 'woodmart' ),
            'name'  => 'woo-single-prod-el-gallery-opt-thumb-left',
            'file'  => '/css/parts/woo-single-prod-el-gallery-opt-thumb-left',
            'rtl'   => true,
        ),
    ),
    'woo-single-prod-el-gallery-opt-thumb-columns'              => array(
        array(
            'title' => esc_html__( 'Single product gallery columns', 'woodmart' ),
            'name'  => 'woo-single-prod-el-gallery-opt-thumb-columns',
            'file'  => '/css/parts/woo-single-prod-el-gallery-opt-thumb-columns',
            'rtl'   => true,
        ),
    ),
);
```

**Let's say I want to remove the following part from above strings?**

```
    'woo-single-prod-el-base'                                   => array(
        array(
            'title' => esc_html__( 'Single product elements base', 'woodmart' ),
            'name'  => 'woo-single-prod-el-base',
            'file'  => '/css/parts/woo-single-prod-el-base',
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: Is there any reason why ui cannot edit the file and delete that code?

Comment: Agreed, it's unclear specifically what the issue is. Have you got dozens of these files, too much to do by hand, or something? Is it always the 3rd one you want to replace, or must it contain a certain piece of text, or something?

Comment: That css file is no longer needed so I want to avoid any additional overhead.

Comment: Ok, but we already understood that. It doesn't explain what you want help with though. If you don't want it in your source code, delete it from your source code. What problem is that causing you?

Comment: Manual editing is of course possible, but all will be lost after the theme update.

Comment: Ah so this is some 3rd-party code? It would have been a good idea to give us the context earlier. Either fork the theme and maintain it yourself, or put it down as a job you must do after updating, or make a request to the person who maintains it to make it more configurable so you can add and remove this stuff as options during the setup or whatever.

Comment: Or if you know the exact snippet you want to remove and it's always the same, you could probably have a quick `grep` script handy to find remove it.

Comment: Actually all strings are initialized with `wp_enqueue_style( )` in another file. So here `wp_dequeue_style()` should remove any of them but unfortunately it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Let say your are storing you returned array result into an array variable called $array, then you can use the following method to delete an array by the key

```
unset($array["woo-single-prod-el-gallery-opt-thumb-left"]);
```

Here is the complete example...

```
<?php

$array=array(
    // Single product.
    'woo-single-prod-opt-review-images'                         => array(
        array(
            'title' =>'Single product review images',
            'name'  => 'woo-single-prod-opt-review-images',
            'file'  => '/css/parts/woo-single-prod-opt-review-images',
        ),
    ),
    'woo-single-prod-el-reviews'                                => array(
        array(
            'title' => 'Single product reviews',
            'name'  => 'woo-single-prod-el-reviews',
            'file'  => '/css/parts/woo-single-prod-el-reviews',
        ),
    ),
    'woo-single-prod-el-base'                                   => array(
        array(
            'title' => 'Single product elements base',
            'name'  => 'woo-single-prod-el-base',
            'file'  => '/css/parts/woo-single-prod-el-base',
        ),
    ),
    'woo-single-prod-el-gallery'                                => array(
        array(
            'title' => 'Single product gallery',
            'name'  => 'woo-single-prod-el-gallery',
            'file'  => '/css/parts/woo-single-prod-el-gallery',
            'rtl'   => true,
        ),
    ),
    'woo-single-prod-el-gallery-opt-thumb-left'                 => array(
        array(
            'title' => 'Single product gallery left',
            'name'  => 'woo-single-prod-el-gallery-opt-thumb-left',
            'file'  => '/css/parts/woo-single-prod-el-gallery-opt-thumb-left',
            'rtl'   => true,
        ),
    ),
    'woo-single-prod-el-gallery-opt-thumb-columns'              => array(
        array(
            'title' => 'Single product gallery columns',
            'name'  => 'woo-single-prod-el-gallery-opt-thumb-columns',
            'file'  => '/css/parts/woo-single-prod-el-gallery-opt-thumb-columns',
            'rtl'   => true,
        ),
    ));
    
    
    
    //Array Before Delete
    echo "<pre>";
    echo print_r($array);
    echo "</pre>";
    
    //Delete Array
    unset($array["woo-single-prod-el-gallery-opt-thumb-left"]);
    
    //Array After Delete
    echo "<pre>";
    echo print_r($array);
    echo "</pre>";
    
?>
```